# Can someone explain the difference between master.tag and page.tag in SAP Commerce/Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

I am not able to comprehend the difference between `master.tag`  and `page.tag` . Can someone please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The view is rendered using JSPs and tag files. JSPs include several tag files to impose a general, reusable structure shown in the following diagram:

[image]

The following tag components are provided in /WEB-INF/tags folder:

[image]